# Overlaying user raster datasets on nasa world wind

Tags: open-source-gis

Currently I am developing a desktop application with Nasa world wind JDK for 3d visualization of my data sets, but when i overlay my raster data sets those are vertically exaggerating with the default elevation layer.Can anyone help me how i can visualize my DEM data(SRTM) on nasa world wind in 3d with its own vertical exaggeration.
Thanks in advance